# Apache SOLR design, searching entire text field or just keywords?

Tags: solr, lucene, django-haystack

For my SOLR setup, I can configure it so when a user searches for some articles in a database, the search engine does a full text search of the entire body text.

However, I also have the code which does a keyword extraction of the body text. Is it recommended to just allow SOLR to perform a full text search on the keywords of an article, or is it still better to let SOLR just perform a full text extraction on the article body itself?

I'd rather not do both, one or the other would be nice. I'm on limited RAM, and can only keep one of the two fields, keywords or the article body.

Reasoning and an answer would be nice, thank you.

Comment: I would say it is recommended to bring into Solr any information that you will need to search on within Solr.  Anything that won't need to be searched doesn't (necessarily) need to be in Solr's index.  If you sometimes need to search keywords, and sometimes need to perform a proper full-text search, I would say you need both.  That really depends on your use case though, I can't tell you which you need.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it recommended to just allow SOLR to perform a full text search on the keywords of an article, or is it still better to let SOLR just perform a full text extraction on the article body itself?

Yes, SOLR is great at full-text indexing. Rather than reinvent the wheel (search algorithms, stop word filtering, boosting, etc) let SOLR index content in your database. If you need to ignore certain words in the article text you can configure stop words in stopwords.txt.